# Filter Custom Dictionary with LINQ ToDictionary - "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"

Tags: vb.net, linq, dictionary, lambda

I have created a Dictionary class (MyDictionary for the example).  I am currently trying to pass MyDictionary into a function, filter it into a new instance of MyDictionary and pass this new instance into another method.

When I am attempting to create the second instance from the filtered first instance of MyDictionary via Lambda Expressions and the ToDictionary Method, I am getting the following error:

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]' to type 'MyDictionary'.**

I have simplified the example and recreated it in LINQPad and am getting the same error.

Here's the simplified version of my code:

```
Sub Main
 Dim di1 As New MyDictionary
 di1(1) = "One"
 di1(2) = "Two"
 di1(3) = "Three"
 di1(4) = "Four"
 Dim di2 As MyDictionary= _
  CType(di1.Where(Function(w) w.Value.Contains("T")) _
   .ToDictionary(Function(tdk) tdk.Key, Function(tdv) tdv.Value), MyDictionary)
End Sub

Public Class MyDictionary
 Inherits Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
 Public Sub New()
  MyBase.New()
 End Sub
 Public Sub New(ByVal dictionary As IDictionary(Of Integer, String))
  MyBase.New(dictionary)
 End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks in advance,
-Aaron

---

Per Brennen's Post:
I am able to do the following and it's fine, I was just hoping to not do it this way.

```
 Sub Main
     Dim di1 As New MyDictionary
     di1(1) = "One"
     di1(2) = "Two"
     di1(3) = "Three"
     di1(4) = "Four"
     Dim di2 = _
      di1.Where(Function(w) w.Value.Contains("T")) _
       .ToDictionary(Function(tdk) tdk.Key, Function(tdv) tdv.Value)
     Dim di3 As New MyDictionary(di2)
 End Sub

Public Class MyDictionary
 Inherits Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
 Public Sub New()
  MyBase.New()
 End Sub
 Public Sub New(ByVal dictionary As IDictionary(Of Integer, String))
  MyBase.New(dictionary)
 End Sub
End Class
```

Does anyone else have any thoughts on how I could skip the third MyDictionary instance?

Comment: Third MyDictionary instance? I only see two.

What you're trying to do is take a MyDictionary, perform some operation on it that returns a Dictionary, and then convert this Dictionary to a MyDictionary. There is no way to do this without having more than one MyDictionary instance. Maybe if you told us what you're trying to accomplish, someone could give you more useful suggestions.

Comment: My apologies.  I said "third MyDictionary instance" but really there is only two.  There is three Dictionary instances overall.
What I am trying to do is pass in a MyDictionary Instance from a source and filter it down and then return the filtered instance.  I have different methods that filter different ways, but that have the same input and output.
At this point two MyDictionary instances are fine, so unless there is something blatantly obvious that I could do different, I'll stick with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

What's being returned from ToDictionary is a Dictionary, not a MyDictionary. MyDictionary is a Dictionary, but not the other way around, so it doesn't make sense to cast from Dictionary to MyDictionary.

In other words, less-derived types can't automagically be converted to more-derived types.

Comment: Thanks Brennen for the quick response.  Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

As [Brennan mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195335/filter-custom-dictionary-with-linq-todictionary-unable-to-cast-object-of-type/3195409#3195409), `MyDictionary` and `Dictionary(Of Integer, String)` are completely different types, even though one derives from the other.

The `ToDictionary` call returns a `Dictionary(Of Integer, String)` and you're then trying to cast that dictionary to a `MyDictionary`.

You could create your own `ToMyDictionary` extension method to workaround this:

```
Dim di2 As MyDictionary = _
    di1.Where(Function(w) w.Value.Contains("T")) _
       .ToMyDictionary(Function(tdk) tdk.Key, Function(tdv) tdv.Value)

' ...

<Extension()>
Public Shared Function ToMyDictionary(Of T)( _
    ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of T), _
    ByVal keySelector As Func(Of T, Integer), _
    ByVal valueSelector As Func(Of T, String)) As MyDictionary

    Dim result As New MyDictionary
    Dim item As T

    For Each item In source
        result.Add(keySelector.Invoke(item), valueSelector.Invoke(item))
    Next

    Return result
End Function
```

*(Apologies if the syntax isn't entirely correct: my VB is very rusty these days.)*

Comment: Thanks LukeH for the suggestion. As much as I love extension methods, I will probably pass on them this time.  It would be a slight overkill at this point.